# Conditonal sum in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I would like to write the formula (in OpenOffice, but I imagine it won't be any different than Excel) to perform the following calculation:

-> Go through the values in column B from B1 to B30 and add them together.
-> Only include the individual number Bn in the sum if An == "value".

So, I want to create a sum of column B but only include the numbers in the sum if their corresponding A column value is some "value".

Comment: Did you try anything or get stuck some where? Did you look at a VLOOKUP or IF statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you could use SUMIF, e.g.

`=SUMIF(A1:A30,"value",B1:B30)`